# Placing unique text from separate worksheet into looped column headers in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic, unique

I am trying to take a column from a separate worksheet and copy it with only its unique values into another worksheet as column headers. Right now, my code makes unique values in reference1 and attempts to copy them over to Sheet1 as column headers, but for some reason, my range only loops the first row in reference1 data (the picture shows it just continually loops title1) into every column header in sheet1. If I place "Transpose(arrValues)" in the with wsDB statement, it only places the first row of data and if I place "Transpose(j)" in the with wsDB statement, it only places the actual numbered columns from the reference1 sheet.

[image]

```
Sub uniqueyes()
Dim wsRef As Worksheet
Dim wsDB As Worksheet

Set wsRef = Worksheets("reference1")
Set wsDB = Worksheets("Sheet1")

With wsRef
    .Range("F1:F60").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=.Range("I1"), unique:=True

    Dim arrValues As Variant
    arrValues = .Range("I2", .Range("I" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

End With

For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

    If Cells(i, 4) = "Title" Then

        For j = 1 To (UBound(arrValues)) Step 1

            With wsDB
            .Range(.Cells(i, j * 4 + 2), .Cells(i, j * 4 + 4)).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrValues)

            End With

        Next j

    End If

Next i

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looping over individual cells so you don't need to use the whole array every time. Since there's only one field to fill it will take the first entry of the array every time. Use the appropriate entry of the array:

```
.Range(.Cells(i, j * 4 + 2), .Cells(i, j * 4 + 4)).Value = arrValues(j)
```

Note that because `arrValues` comes from a column, it is a one-dimensional array.

Comment: I've tried this but it just keeps telling me the subscript is out of range